# how to java path when jre is on shared drive on same network

Tags: java, environment-variables

assume jre is shared on below path, And, I tried below command from my pc
set PATH=\10.2.151.6\WIP\Jre\bin;%PATH%

Can someone help to set java path when jre is on shared drive??

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to use network addresses in the `PATH` environment variable, so I'd advise you to create a drive mapping and a this drive to the `PATH` variable.

By the way, I believe the network path starts with two backslashes:

```
\\10.2.151.6\WIP\Jre\bin
```

Comment: sorry, its typo, actually it has two backslashes only.
set PATH=\\10.2.151.6\WIP\Jre\bin;%PATH%